# ut aMultiplication of matrices problems

Tags: r, matrix

I am using a script found in "A user's guide to functional indices" to calculate a functional diversity index. However, the script has been riddled with bugs and issues. I have managed to now get the script to run but it produces the incorrect answer.

It uses three matrices which are as follows:

abundance:

```
        S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8 S9
Palm    6  3  0  1  0 16  0  2  3
Forest  2  0  2  1  2  1  3  0  2
```

minsp:

```
       min
S1 25.3038
S2 19.5750
S3 60.5880
S4 16.2864
S5 46.1040
S6 10.9056
S7  8.7570
S8  2.1289
S9  4.1730
```

maxsp:

```
       max
S1 44.7344
S2 22.6966
S3 75.1817
S4 17.8176
S5 50.7472
S6 33.3660
S7 14.3341
S8  3.3947
S9 10.2510
```

I think it should produce two different numbers depending on the two sites `Palm` and `Forest`. Instead it produces two of the exact same numbers. I have looked at it and found that the problem seams to steam from these lines of code:

```
Siteminsp <- abundance*minsp 
Siteminsp <- minsp[apply(Siteminsp,1,function (x) sum(x,na.rm=T))!=0, ,drop = FALSE]

Sitemaxsp <- abundance*maxsp 
Sitemaxsp <- maxsp[apply(Sitemaxsp,1,function (x) sum(x,na.rm=T))!=0, ,drop = FALSE]
```

Rather than `abundance*minsp` producing a new matrix where the min value for each species has been multiplied by the abundance of that species at each site. The function is multiplying the first species abundance by the first species min value, then the first species abundance in the other site to the second min value, then the second species abundance by the third value and so on.

Have I miss understood what should be happening here?

Can someone please explain to be what is going wrong as I am completely out of ideas. Here is the whole script if it is helpful:

```
rownames(Abundance1) <- Abundance1[,1]
Abundance <- Abundance1[,-1]
Abundance <- Abundance[,order(colnames(Abundance))]

rownames(min1) <- min1[,1]
minsp <- min1[,-1, drop= FALSE]
minsp <- minsp[order(rownames(min1)), , drop = FALSE]

rownames(max1) <- max1[,1]
maxsp <- max1[,-1, drop=FALSE]
maxsp <- maxsp[order(rownames(max1)), , drop = FALSE]

globalFRI <- function(minsp,maxsp) {
  deltaS <- list()

  for (j in 1:ncol(minsp))
  {
    xx <- cbind(minsp[,j], maxsp[,j])
    xx <- xx[apply(xx,1,function(z) sum(is.finite(z))==2),]
    xx <- xx[order(xx[,1]),]
    z <- c(0, nrow(xx))
    i <- 1
    b <- xx[1, 2]
    while ( i < nrow(xx) )
    {
      if (b < xx[i+1,1]) z <- c(z, i)
      b <- ifelse(b >= xx[i+1,2], b, xx[i+1,2])
      i <- i+1
      if (i==nrow(xx)) break
    }
    group <- factor(rep(1:(length(z)-1), diff(sort(z))))
    deltaS[[j]] <- tapply(xx[,2], group, max) - tapply(xx[,1], group, min)
  }

  globalFRIs <- sapply(deltaS, sum)}

globalFRIAll <- globalFRI(minsp,maxsp)

Abundance2 <- Abundance
Abundance2[Abundance2 != 0] <- 1
abundance <- data.matrix(Abundance)

IndexFRIs <- function(Abundance,minsp,maxsp,globalFRI) {

  Siteminsp <- abundance*minsp 
  Siteminsp <- minsp[apply(Siteminsp,1,function (x) sum(x,na.rm=T))!=0, ,drop = FALSE]

  Sitemaxsp <- abundance*maxsp 
  Sitemaxsp <- maxsp[apply(Sitemaxsp,1,function (x) sum(x,na.rm=T))!=0, ,drop = FALSE]

  deltaS <- list()
  for (j in 1:ncol(Siteminsp))
  {
    xx <- cbind(Siteminsp[,j], Sitemaxsp[,j])
    xx <- xx[apply(xx,1,function(z) sum(is.finite(z))==2),]
    xx <- xx[order(xx[,1]),]
    z <- c(0, nrow(xx))
    i <- 1
    b <- xx[1, 2]
    while ( i < nrow(xx) )
    {
      if (b < xx[i+1,1]) z <- c(z, i)
      b <- ifelse(b >= xx[i+1,2], b, xx[i+1,2])
      i <- i+1
      if (i==nrow(xx)) break
    }
    group <- factor(rep(1:(length(z)-1), diff(sort(z))))
    deltaS[[j]] <- tapply(xx[,2], group, max) - tapply(xx[,1], group, min)
  }
  RI <- sapply(deltaS, sum)
  FRI1 <- RI/globalFRI
  FRIs <-  mean(FRI1)

}

FRIs <- apply(Abundance2,1,IndexFRIs,minsp,maxsp,globalFRIAll)
```

dput(abundance):

```
structure(c(6L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 16L, 1L, 
0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 2L), .Dim = c(2L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(c("Palm", 
"Forest"), c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", 
"S9")))
```

dput(minsp):

```
structure(list(min = c(25.3038, 19.575, 60.588, 16.2864, 46.104, 
10.9056, 8.757, 2.1289, 4.173)), .Names = "min", row.names = c("S1", 
"S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", "S9"), class = "data.frame")
```

dput(maxsp):

```
structure(list(max = c(44.7344, 22.6966, 75.1817, 17.8176, 50.7472, 
33.366, 14.3341, 3.3947, 10.251)), .Names = "max", row.names = c("S1", 
"S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", "S9"), class = "data.frame")
```

I think the output for abundance*minsp should be something like this:

```
      Palm    Forest
S1  151.8228  50.6076
S2  58.725    0
S3  0         121.176
S4  16.2864   16.2864
S5  92.208    0
S6  174.489   10.9056
S7  0         26.271
S8  4.2578    0
S9  8.346     12.519
```

Comment: Matrix-matrix multiplication in R is performed using the `%*%` operator.

Comment: To make this example reproducible, post the output of `dput(abundance)`, `dput(minsp)` and `dput(maxsp)`. Then, post what is your desired output.

Comment: @nicola Ive added the dput outputs you asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually not looking for matrix multiplication but to multiply two vectors together:

```
> apply(abundance, 1, `*`, unlist(minsp))
#       Palm   Forest
#S1 151.8228  50.6076
#S2  58.7250   0.0000
#S3   0.0000 121.1760
#S4  16.2864  16.2864
#S5   0.0000  92.2080
#S6 174.4896  10.9056
#S7   0.0000  26.2710
#S8   4.2578   0.0000
#S9  12.5190   8.3460
```

Or even better:

```
t(abundance) * unlist(minsp)
```

Comment: Thank you! This has sorted the abundance*minsp problem. If you have a moment could you explain the purpose of the line 
`Siteminsp <- minsp[apply(Siteminsp,1,function (x) sum(x,na.rm=T))!=0, ,drop = FALSE]`

all it seems to be doing is returning that matrix to the original minsp

Comment: Nevermind, I've figured it out. Thanks again for your solution